# Android in-app import CSV limit?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to my application in Google Play. There are more than 2.000 products. During the import, only some 150 were uploaded, and since then I'm not able to import the rest. Below is the description of what I'm facing...

1. I have created CSV file with over 2.000 products
2. It has been processed, but only some 150 products were saved
3. I'm trying to upload the same file again, with 'overwrite' checked and I'm repeatedly receiving the information: "Cannot process sent file. Check, whether the limit is not exceeded."

Does anyone have a similar problem? Which browsers where you using to manage the import?
Maybe there are some undocumented limits, for the number of products, available through in-app billing?

Best regards,
Tomasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get better luck by contacting Google Play developer support. Or, just split your CSV into 100 line chunks and import one by one.

Comment: I even tried spliting it into files containing only 100 or even 10 records, still no luck.
I have posted this question everywhere it was possible, but don't know when will I receive any responses...

Comment: Try this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136601

Comment: I've tried that. I even posted a ticket here: http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/
Still waiting for any answers :)

Comment: Well, I know the solution. This problem was caused by a too long title. Anyway - the message was not clear thus it was just a luck, to find it out..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know the solution. This problem was caused by a too long title. Anyway - the message was not clear thus it was just a luck, to find it out..